# Reload viewcontroller

Tags: reload, viewdidload

How can I refresh a viewcontroller?.
I.e. I have a series of animations that run into the viewdidload and want to reload the viewcontroller again, really it would be reload the viewdidload again?

It would be an action assigned to a UIButton

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should do it by that way:

```
   - (void)viewDidLoad {
         [self setUpInterface];
    }

    //for UIButton Action
    - (IBAction)buttonTapped: (id)sender {
         [self setUpInterface];
    }

    //for your aninmations
    - (void)setUpInterface {
    //your code for animation here
    }
```

don't try to call viewDidLoad, it isn't good. Goodluck!

Comment: It is correct that tells. But my problem is as follows:

I have several balls that move to a certain point, PressedButton.center CGPointMake(784, 340);                           , but the original position do it through the storyboard, I want to reload that view completely.                                                   
Thank you very much for your interest.